# Forecast time series returns error in decompose

Tags: r, forecasting

A time series forecasting script returns the following error:

```
library(forecast) # version 6.1

myfc = forecast(myts)  # see ts object below
Error in decompose(y, type = switch(seasontype, A = "additive", M = "multiplicative")) : 
  unused argument (type = switch(seasontype, A = "additive", M = "multiplicative"))
```

I don't see a related argument in `?forecast`, so I do not know where this error comes from. The code worked previously and I updated my all packages recently, so it may be related to a change in the forecast package.

here is the time series object and sessionInfo():

```
dput(myts)
structure(c(990145L, 829021L, 999845L, 882279L, 965694L, 984126L, 
1096175L, 1042494L, 1019237L, 917413L, 867656L, 974873L, 952704L, 
832167L, 900177L, 920919L, 945841L, 1000145L, 1114392L, 980026L, 
887912L, 911315L, 841159L, 787133L, 891182L, 809643L, 826410L, 
793796L, 856537L, 841324L, 959904L, 954611L, 883759L, 830928L, 
862569L, 930569L, 896312L, 793851L, 824419L, 718283L, 835346L, 
878511L, 834560L, 890681L, 857262L, 836667L, 747833L, 921598L, 
966345L, 858136L, 842052L, 821675L, 865784L, 887827L, 957823L, 
898431L, 846662L, 764570L, 774115L, 881166L), .Tsp = c(2009, 
2013.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forecast_6.1      timeDate_3012.100 zoo_1.7-12       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6 parallel_3.2.1   tools_3.2.1      nnet_7.3-10      Rcpp_0.11.6      fracdiff_1.4-2   tseries_0.10-34  grid_3.2.1       lattice_0.20-31  quadprog_1.5-5
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Works perfectly fine for me. Try restarting your R session maybe.

Comment: Works for me. What is your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: By chance, do you have package `Rssa` also loaded?

Comment: @Pascal - added sessionInfo, Rssa not loaded.

Comment: @David Arenburg - I restarted the R session and now it works. So now the question is how I can find the conflict.

Comment: Is it the info from the session you get error or after you restarted R?

Comment: It's not necessarily a conflict with some package rather it could be that you messed some function/dependency while running your script

Comment: @Pascal - I restarted to see if David's suggestion worked, so it is after. I am trying to reproduce the issue now.

Comment: @David Arenburg - in that case the question is: how do find out what happened with the function/dependency. Because the script worked previously and because the the error message isn't helpful in this case, that's not easy for me. I am worried about the code stability.

Comment: The error message suggests that `forecast` is trying to use `decompose` with argument `type`, but the available `decompose` function doesn't have such argument. This suggest the `decompose` function from `stats` to be hidden by a function `decompose` from another package. That is why I asked about `Rssa` which has its own `decompose` function. If you get this error again, type `?decompose` and see what pops up.

Comment: @Pascal, thanks, good idea, will do. I can't reproduce the error anymore, which worries me more than a consistent crash.